# Call javascript function from in objective c + sencha touch

Tags: javascript, objective-c, sencha-touch, appdelegate

I am creating 1 application in mobile.

From appdelegate (iphone), I want to call javascript which is residing in my controler of sencha touch.Can anybody help me out?

I am really stuck.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put your javascript code ..

Comment: from appdelegate, i want to call some function.javascript function..js code is in controller (sencha touch)

Comment: use NSULConnecton..for get js data :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a Custom URL Scheme.

Sencha API Docs will tell you to add the following code to your application ::

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Sencha',
requires: ['Ext.device.Device'],
launch: function() {
    if (Ext.device.Device.scheme) {
        // the application was opened via another application. Do something:
        alert('Applicaton pened via another application: ' + Ext.device.Device.scheme.url);
    }

    // Listen for future changes
    Ext.device.Device.on('schemeupdate', function(device, scheme) {
        // the application was launched, closed, and then launched another from another application
        // this means onReady will not be called again (because the application is already running in the 
        // background) - but this event will be fired
        alert('Applicated reopened via another application: ' + scheme.url);
    }, this);
}
});
```

To ensure this works, add the custom URLS you want to use while packaging your application as follows in your packager.json file ::

```
{
...
"rawConfig": "<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key><array><dict><key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key><array><string>sencha</string></array><key>CFBundleURLName</key><string>com.sencha.example</string></dict></array>"
...
}
```

Edit :: This currently only works with the Sencha Native Packager, and not Phonegap.